# fadeIn and faceOut effect in Jquery not working correct

Tags: jquery

This script works fine on `single click` but on `double click` it shows both the divs `#btnn` and `#num`

CSS

```
#num
{
    padding: 15px;
    display: none;
}
```

JQ

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".deatil_view_b").toggle(function() {
        $("#btnn").fadeOut('slow',function() {
            $("#num").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }, function(){
        $("#num").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $("#btnn").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: try adding "return false;" to each function.

Comment: @SamTyson not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".detail_view_b").toggle(function() {
        $("#btnn").fadeOut('slow', function() {
            $("#num").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    }, function() {
        $("#num").fadeOut('slow', function() {
             $("#btnn").fadeIn('slow');
        });
    });
    $(".detail_view_b").dblclick(function() {
        $("#btnn").clearQueue();
        $("#num").clearQueue();
    });
});
```

Also note that I corrected "deatil_view_b" to "detail_view_b". I'm assuming that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.stop()` function to complete the animations instantly and proceed:

```
$("#btnn").stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow',function() {
    $("#num").fadeIn('slow');
});

$("#num").stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow', function() {
     $("#btnn").fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Remember that double click isn't a standard event in web apps though.